# i have sql script which uses two query to get the result that i expect , how can i achieve this with the single query ,example below

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

1. query1 where condition = "condition1" ; queryresult1 = number1
2. query2 where condition = "condition2" ; queryresult2 = number2

I want number1-number2 , how can i make this possible with just a single query

Comment: Try to provide a better example of exactly what you are doing, so that 'obvious syntax issues' are not on the forefront of everyone's mind ;) Plus, is that number1 MINUS number2, or is that concat together, or what? Please re-edit your question to be a bit more clear.

Comment: If you provide more details and show what you have tried, we may be able to assist you in providing better solutions. Otherwise it would just  be a guessing game with insufficient information.

Comment: select (val1-val2) as result from (select sal from emp where name = someName) as val1 ,(select sal from emp where name = someOtherName )as val2             sorry for not thinking from viewers point of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming i understand your question correctly, easiest way is joining two table and perform your whatever calculation.

```
select valueone, valuetwo, valueone - valuetwo as finalresult
  from (select 18 as valueone from dual where 1 = 1) -- query one)
 inner join (select 6 as valuetwo from dual where 1 = 1) -- query two)
    on 1 = 1 -- join condition
 where 1 = 1; -- some condition
```

Comment: i had a complex query, but this was what i was expecting,i am sorry for not being clear when i posted